# Distinguish between different controls posting the same form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a simple page with two drop downs, one for country and one for cities in that country. When the user selects a country in the list I post the form and update the city list accordingly.

The Show button posts the same form.

I want to distinguish between a user selecting a country and clicking the Show button (different actions) what is the best way to do this?

[image: controls]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give your Show submit button a name:

```
<button type="submit" name="show">Show</button>
```

and then in the controller action check for the presence of the `show` parameter in the request. If it is present it means that the form was submitted after clicking on the `Show` button. For the other case you will have to use javascript and manually submit the form by either calling `.submit()` or using AJAX. In both cases though the `show` parameter will not be present in the request.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(string show)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(show))
    {
        // the form was submitted with the Show button
    }
    else
    {
        // ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are showing the same form with either method, I assume you have taken it into a seperate function and are calling it from the button_click and the dropdown_selectedindexchanged.

You could also pass it a boolean say buttonClicked, such that if the user clicked the button it send a true value, and if they updated the combobox it passes a false value, and then in the showForm() method, have an if statement:

```
private void showButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     theCountry = countryDropDown.selectedItem.toString();
     showForm(theCountry, true);
}

private void countryDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    theCountry = countryDropDown.selectedItem.toString();
    showForm(theCountry, false);
}

private void showForm(string theCountry, bool buttonClicked)
{
    if(button)
    {
        //whatever code you want to run when the button is clicked but not when the combobox is changed
    }
    else
    {   
         // whatever code you want to run when the combobox is changed but not when the button is clicked
    }
//the code that is the same for both
}
```